# Dynamically assign a CSS class from within CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to dynamically assign a class to an existing class? I am trying to allocate a style to the first child like this:

```
.active {
  color: red;
}

item:first-child .item_text {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  /* make it active class */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is simply not possible with just CSS.

The best you could do:

```
.active,
item:first-child .item_text {
  color: red;
}

item:first-child .item_text {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

---

It is possible if you used a CSS preprocessor like LESS or SASS, which among others extend CSS with functionality like including/extending classes.

In LESS

```
item:first-child .item_text {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  .active;
}
```

This would literally replace that classname with the `color: red;` line.

In SASS (from version 3, which uses the "SCSS" syntax):

```
item:first-child .item_text {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  @extend .active;
}
```

This would render the same output as my CSS example above.